# why do I keep getting the error Cannot resolve symbol Fragment activity?

Tags: java, android

Why does it keep showing up red If I have the library imported?

[image]

Comment: How have you imported the appcompat library?

Comment: yes that would be import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: has the library "android.support.v4" been imported into the project? Like in the "libs" folder? You may need to restart the IDE

Comment: hey i downloaded the libraries on the extras on sdk. But the lib folder appears to be empty? any pointers?

Comment: @J.B. `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;` imports the `FragmentActivity` **class** into the current .java file. You also need to import the full appcompat library into Eclipse and reference it from your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the appcompat library into your project.  For details how to do this, see [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).